# Using radio buttons and check boxes for similar task (Android)

Tags: java, android

I have a EditText view and a checkBox (hide), and two radioButtons (hide and show).  The function of the buttons and checkbox is to hide or show the hinto the EditView.  I guess the first question is why I'd want to do this in the first place.  Well, I'm totally new to android and I'm just trying different things out.

When I run the code though, the Activity fails to launch.  I tested the program before I even placed any radio buttons, and it was working just fine with only the check box in the program. So I'm assuming the problem lies somewhere with the radio buttons, or a combination of both used for the same task.

here's my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

public class EmPubLiteActivity extends Activity implements
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

CheckBox cb;
EditText et;
RadioButton rbHide;
RadioButton rbShow;
RadioGroup rg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    cb = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbHideHint);
    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    rbHide = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbHide);
    rbShow = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbShow);

    RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this);
    rg.addView(rbHide);
    rg.addView(rbShow);
    rbHide.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    rbShow.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.em_pub_lite, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {

    switch (view.getId()) {

    case R.id.cbHideHint:
        if (isChecked) {
            et.setHint(R.string.nothing);
            rbHide.setChecked(true);
        }
        else {
            et.setHint(R.string.text_here);
            rbShow.setChecked(true);
        }
        break;
    case R.id.rbHide:
            et.setHint(R.string.nothing);
            cb.setChecked(false);
        break;
    case R.id.rbShow:
            et.setHint(R.string.text_here);
            cb.setChecked(true);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following error, along with a bunch of others, but I have a feeling this is where the problem is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: the specified child already has a parent. 
You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

What does this error mean, and how can I fix it?

Comment: but if you have already declared radio button in xml file then why are you again add it dynamically???

Comment: @Piyush Gupta : yeah, pretty much solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rbHide = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbHide);
rbShow = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbShow);

RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this);
rg.addView(rbHide);
rg.addView(rbShow);
rbHide.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
rbShow.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

In your layout xml, `rbHide` and `rbShow` is already a child of its parent view. Now you add them to a newly created view without removing them from their parent. You should define the RadioGroup inside the layout xml instead of creating them in code. It should look like this:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checkedButton="@+id/rbHide" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbHide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbShow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RadioGroup>
```